# Restrict entry to a group of cells based on the value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I am creating a work schedule where the staff enters their own schedules.  I only want a certain number of staff each shift. I already use `COUNTIF` to show the number of staff signed up for each shift. How can I restrict entry into the staff members' cell if the `COUNTIF` cell has reached the maximum number of staff?

For example, if I have ten staff members and only need six each day, can I restrict staffing by those other three by blocking entry to those cells?

Comment: On the spreadsheet I have, each employee has their own row.  They add their shift type in the cells of each column to create their schedule.  Would this formula work with that setup?

Answer (score 0):

- select rows where they can type and create restricted data validation with this custom formula:


  ```
  =COUNTA($B$2:$B$10)<=$B$1
  ```

[image: 1]